# Destroying Documents with Nano in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I am working on building my first REST API in Node.js/Express 4. I'm working with a Couchdb via Nano. I've got things down for Get, Put and Post, however Delete is causing some problems. I'm getting the doc to delete but I am getting a 404 in response. I am also trying to write the proper test for this in Mocha, which is how I'm getting the 404, along with testing by hand with Postman.

Here is what I have so far:

In my route:

```
router.delete('/:bear_id', function(req, res, done) {
  console.log("deleting..." + req.params.bear_id);
  bears.get(req.params.bear_id, function(err, body, header) {
    if (!err) {
      bears.destroy(req.params.bear_id, body._rev, function(err, body, header) {
        if (!err) {
          res.send(200, { message: "deleted " + req.params.bear_id});
        }
      });
    }
    done();
  });
});
```

In my test:

```
it('DELETE api/bears should delete the test_bear', function(done){
  var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/bears/test_bear'
  };
  setTimeout( function() {

    request.del(options , function(err, res, body){
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      expect(res.body).to.equal('{"message":"deleted test_bear"}');
      done(err);
    });
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`done()` is being called out of turn due to the asynchronous nature of **node.js**.

This is causing **express** to check for the next route which is most likely your route for `404` or no route.

```
router.delete('/:bear_id', function(req, res, done) {
  console.log("deleting..." + req.params.bear_id);
  bears.get(req.params.bear_id, function(err, body, header) {
    if(err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    bears.destroy(req.params.bear_id, body._rev, function(err, body, header) {
      if(err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return res.send(200, { message: "deleted " + req.params.bear_id});
    });
  });
});
```

Note: I'd suggest changing `done` to `next` in your routes as it better describes the actual process of **express** routing.

Comment: thank you so much! That worked like a charm and makes the asynchronous calls make more sense.